# Maven needs to reimport a dependency every time I switch branches and does not take the -o option

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, dependencies

I'm having an issue with Maven on Intellij 2019.3 (but can't be solved in command line so I assume this is really  a maven issue).
I have a dependency in my local repository that I have downloaded before. I've reimported my pom.xml, did a clean-install. And all was well until I changed branches. This other branch also added this dependency, on another module so I had to reimport again. A while later I checked out to the former branch and I had to reimport again  or my code wouldn't compile. Went back to the latter branch, had to do it again... In short, I have to reimport dependencies everytime I switch branches, although I've done it before. I never had this issue on this project, to which we add new dependencies regularly.

The other thing I can't wrap my head around is that maven is always looking for the dependency in the distant repository, while I have it locally. I tried running mvn install with the offline option:
`mvn clean install -DskipTests -X -o`
it still tried to access the distant repository, and this is a problem because I can't access it at all times. I also tried to remove the _remote.repositories and jar.lastUpdated files as advised somewhere else on stack, but to no avail.

If someone has encountered one of these problems and can offer advice, thank you

Comment: Maven cannot "reimport" a POM. This seems to be an IntelliJ thing.

Comment: That looks `jar.lastUpdated` like other issues...